# AWS Multi-account AWS Cloudformation execution

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codestar

Codestar generates a pipeline where the deploy has two steps:
GenerateChangeSet and ExecuteChangeSet

[image]

I've read this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/pipelines-create-cross-account.html but it's related to CodeDeploy.

I want to run the deploy (AWS Cloudformation) steps in another account.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, I'm analyzing StackSet to do that.